# Sound normalization

Tags: sound

This is my first installation of Ubuntu (18.10), and the first thing I noticed is that sound quality of any media is very bad (compared to Windows). 
Most noticeable is absence of normalization of sound levels, watching movies without that becomes real pain, speech is silent, sound effects are loud and vice versa.
In windows sound normalization is achieved by checking the check box, is there any similar way to do it in Ubuntu? Without getting PhD in console typing, because all the posts I found on this topic are too complicated (assumed that some things are obvious, whereas even opening a file to edit in Ubuntu is a challenge for me, so such posts are not useful). A manual for absolute beginners how to do this crucial thing could be very useful for many people.

Comment: You are thinking of compression, not normalization. If you want to shrink the dynamic range from movie theatre level to something suited for laptop computers, you want compression. See the plugin mentioned in @danzel's link.

Comment: I just tried PulseEffects which is suggested in a more recent answer to that question. It is a lot easier to set up and use than the compressor plugin and has a lot more functionality.

Comment: @danzel Thanks for link, that's what I need. You may convert it into answer, better than in link, providing your `pulseeffects` presets for movies and music, and install instructions

Comment: @LeonidMew this question has been closed as a duplicate so I edited the answer I linked to to include installation instructions.